# Magic mode ignoring updates to custom object

Tags: ractivejs

Please see [this pen](http://codepen.io/jonahx/pen/dbff988f46defb41d212a7db63f570fb) for a demo of the issue (based on the slideshow from the tutorial).  When clicking on "next" and "prev" arrows, you'll notice that the `imgIndex` mustache updates correctly, but the expression mustaches such as `<p>{{ curImageCaption() }}</p>` do not recognize when their values are changing.

That is, the object is mutated such that the mustache value would change if the expressions were re-evaluated, but ractive doesn't seem to realize that.  Is there any way to get this to work, barring writing adaptors?  Am I misunderstanding how magic mode works?  The interesting thing is that even if I explicitly call `ractive.update()` inside the event handlers, ractive still doesn't respond.

### UPDATE WITH NEW INFO

After more fiddling, I came up with [this hack](http://codepen.io/jonahx/pen/a7dc88989cedf010a2b9369218ca5b56) that gets it working.  The hack is to change, eg, `<p>{{ curImageCaption() }}</p>` to `<p>{{ curImageCaption(imgIndex) }}</p>` -- adding a simple primitive to the mustache expression which ractive understands how to watch correctly.

I think I see what's going on now, but having to explicitly add arguments to the mustache expression containing changing primitives defeats much of the purpose of having the separate domain object -- that is, now you are coding your domain object with ractive in mind, using changing primitives a sort of basic pub/sub mechanism for notifying ractive of changes.

Having to create a real pub/sub mechanism on my custom objects, which ractive then explicitly subscribes to, would be fine.  The problem is, as I noted in the OP, even when ractive is notified of a change via `ractive.update()`, it still doesn't know it should recompute the mustaches unless I use the fake argument hack. So it's not clear what callback ractive should be registering to make everything work.

I don't understand the inner-working of ractive well enough to do this, but I suspect what's needed is the ability to directly work with the `_deps` stuff, and manually trigger recomputes for expressions.  If this sounds right, an example of how to accomplish it would be appreciated.

### UPDATE 2 -- A decent solution

Here is a [proof of concept for a not-too-hacky workaround](http://codepen.io/jonahx/pen/68035f20f8ad3d4fbc8efeff307e34c3).

The idea is to use ECMA5 properties to decorate your custom domain object, providing properties that delegate to the existing methods you want to use but which don't work inside ractive templates.  The properties, otoh, work just fine.

So instead of `<p>{{ curImageCaption() }}</p>` we simply write `<p>{{ imageCaption }}</p>`, and then we decorate our custom domain object like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(mySlideshow, "imageCaption", {
  configurable: true,
  get: function() { return this.curImageCaption() },
  set: function() { }
});
```

This decoration, a bit verbose in my demo, can easily be slimmed down by creating a helper method which accepts an object mapping your new ractive-friendly property names to names of existing methods on your object, and takes care of the above boilerplate for you.

NOTE: One drawback of this method is that you do have to call `ractive.update()` manually in your event handlers.  I'd like to know if there's a way of getting around that.  And if there is not, how big of a performance hit does this cause?  Does it defeat the whole purpose of ractive's surgical updates?

### Update 3 -- A better decent solution?

[This pen](http://codepen.io/jonahx/pen/e38979b5c81d1b115ac6d7f5481eb7dc) takes yet another approach, in which link our custom domain model with ractive via a generic dispatcher object (an object that implements `notify()`).  I think this is my favorite of the approaches so far....

It's similar to the official [ractive adaptors](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/wiki/Adaptors), but we are using DI to pass our unofficial ractive adapter to our domain object, rather than wrapping our object.  At first glance it might seem we are "coding to ractive," but in fact this is only partially true.  Even if we were using another framework, we'd need to use some notification mechanism to broadcast changes to our view model so that views could react to it.  This DI approach seems to require less boilerplate than official ractive adaptors, though I don't understand them well enough to know this for sure.  It is not as completely general a solution as the official adaptors either.

### Code from pen for posterity

#### HTML

```
<div id='output'></div>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
  <div class='slideshow'>
    <div class='main'>
      <a class='prev' on-tap='prev'><span>&laquo;</span></a>
      <div class='main-image' style='background-image: url({{ curImageSrc() }});'></div>
      <a class='next' on-tap='next'><span>&raquo;</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class='caption'>
      <p>{{ curImageCaption() }}</p>
      <p>Image index: {{ imgIndex }} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

#### JS

```
// Fix JS modular arithmetic to always return positive numbers
function mod(m, n) { return ((m%n)+n)%n; }

function SlideshowViewModel(imageData) {
  var self = this;
  self.imgIndex = 0;
  self.next = function() { self.setLegalIndex(self.imgIndex+1); }
  self.prev = function() { self.setLegalIndex(self.imgIndex-1); }
  self.curImage = function() { return imageData[self.imgIndex]; }
  self.curImageSrc = function() { return self.curImage().src; }
  self.curImageCaption = function() { return self.curImage().caption; }
  self.setLegalIndex = function(newIndex) { self.imgIndex = mod(newIndex, imageData.length); } 
}

var mySlideshow = new SlideshowViewModel(
  [
    { src: imgPath('problem.gif'), caption: 'Trying to work out a problem after the 5th hour' },
    { src: imgPath('css.gif'), caption: 'Trying to fix someone else\'s CSS' },
    { src: imgPath('ie.gif'), caption: 'Testing interface on Internet Explorer' },
    { src: imgPath('w3c.gif'), caption: 'Trying to code to W3C standards' },
    { src: imgPath('build.gif'), caption: 'Visiting the guy that wrote the build scripts' },
    { src: imgPath('test.gif'), caption: 'I don\'t need to test that. What can possibly go wrong?' }
  ]
);

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#output',
  template: '#template',
  data: mySlideshow,
  magic: true
});

ractive.on( 'next', function(event) {
  ractive.data.next(); 
});
ractive.on( 'prev', function(event) {
  ractive.data.prev(); 
});


function imgPath(name) { return 'http://learn.ractivejs.org/files/gifs/' + name; }
```

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, [you should still post it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (or possibly several answers if they are very different!) rather than editing it into the question. This makes it clearer to readers that an answer has been found, and makes it clearer where the problem ends and the solution begins.

Comment: I am planning to do this, but I would first like to hear from Rich Harris to get feedback on my proposed answers.  That is, I don't yet consider them "answers" -- only ideas so far.

Comment: An answer doesn't have to be perfect. A question can have many answers at once, and the "best" one will be voted highest and accepted. (Also, who's Rich Harris, and why does he get the final say?)

Comment: He's the author of ractive.js

Comment: Ah fair enough. Still, this is a community site, and to this site, your answers may well be valid answers, even if they don't turn out to be the final answer that gets marked as "valid" for reference by future readers. This post feels like you're expecting a forum thread with back and forth (you refer to your own first paragraph as "the OP"), and eventually an answer emerging, which doesn't really fit this site's format IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I agree the post has turned into a bit of a mess.  As I said, I plan to clean it up but am waiting for a couple more days as I expect Rich to chime in, and I'll be able to make a better, more coherent final edit after getting his input.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll stop poking my nose in and leave you to it. Best of luck finding an elegant solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try and explain what's going on under the hood before presenting a possible solution:

### Wrapping objects in magic mode

In magic mode, when Ractive encounters an unwrapped *data descriptor* of an object, it *wraps* it by replacing it with an *accessor descriptor* - the `get()/set()` functions. ([More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), for those interested.) So when you do `self.imgIndex = 1`, you're actually triggering the `set()` function, which knows how to notify all the *dependants* of the `imgIndex` property.

The key word here is 'encounters'. The only way Ractive knows that it needs to wrap `imgIndex` is if we do `ractive.get('imgIndex')`. This happens internally because we have an `{{imgIndex}}` mustache.

So that's why the index property updates.

### Dependency tracking with computed values

Within an ordinary template, you can have what basically amount to computed values, using the `get()` method:

```html
<p>{{ curImageCaption() }}</p>
```

```js
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  template: template,
  data: {
    images: images,
    imgIndex: 0,
    curImageCaption: function () {
      var imgIndex = this.get( 'imgIndex' );
      return this.get( 'images' )[ imgIndex ].caption;
    }
  }
});
```

Here, because we're calling `ractive.get()` inside the `curImageCaption` function, Ractive knows that it needs to rerun the function each time either `images` or `imgIndex` changes.

What you're in effect asking is a reasonable question: why doesn't retrieving the value of `self.imgIndex` in magic mode work the same as doing `ractive.get('imgIndex')`?

The answer comes in two parts: Firstly, I hadn't thought of adding that feature, and secondly, it turns out it doesn't work! Or rather, it's extremely fragile. I changed magic mode so that the `get()` accessor captured the dependency the same way `ractive.get()` does - but `self.imgIndex` is only an accessor descriptor (as opposed to a data descriptor) *if Ractive has already encountered it*. So it worked when we had `<p>Image index: {{ imgIndex }} </p>` at the top of the template, but not when it's at the bottom!

Normally the prescription would be fairly simple: use `ractive.get()` to make the dependency on `self.imgIndex` explicit inside `curImageSrc()` and `curImageCaption()`. But because you're using a custom viewmodel object, that's not ideal because it effectively means hard-coding keypaths.

### A solution - creating a custom adaptor

Here's what I'd recommend - making an adaptor that works with the custom viewmodel object:

```js
Ractive.adaptors.slides = {
  filter: function ( object ) {
    return object instanceof SlideshowViewModel;
  },
  wrap: function ( ractive, slides, keypath, prefix ) {
    var originalNext, originalPrev;

    // intercept next() and prev()
    originalNext = slides.next;
    slides.next = function () {
      originalNext.call( slides );
      ractive.update( keypath );
    };

    originalPrev = slides.prev;
    slides.prev = function () {
      originalPrev.call( slides );
      ractive.update( keypath );
    };

    return {
      get: function () {
        return {
          current: slides.curImage(),
          index: slides.imgIndex
        };
      },
      teardown: function () {
        slides.next = originalNext;
        slides.prev = originalPrev;
      }
    };
  }
};

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#output',
  template: '#template',
  data: mySlideshow,
  adaptors: [ 'slides' ]
});
```

This is a very simple adaptor, and it could probably be improved, but you get the gist - we're intercepting calls to `next()` and `prev()`, and letting Ractive know (via `ractive.update()`) that it needs to do some dirty checking. Note that we're presenting a facade (via the `get()` method of the wrapper), so the template looks slightly different - [see this pen](http://codepen.io/Rich-Harris/pen/LhJiA).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks rich!  follow up questions: 1. can you offer any thoughts/critiques of my "update 3" solution?  it seems a bit more concise than the official ractive adaptor -- so i'm curious about the drawbacks.  2. in your version of `curImageCaption` which uses `this.get( 'imgIndex' );` instead of `this.imgIndex`, how does ractive accomplish its metaprogramming magic?  how does it know `this.get( 'imgIndex')` is being called inside the mustache function `{curImageCaption()}`? does it just run it at template compile time and check if get was called somehow?

Comment: One other point I meant to make: With the solution I offered in "Update 3", we don't even need to use magic mode.  If you take a look, you'll see I even replaced the ViewModel with a version that uses revealing module pattern.   I believe the official adaptor method has this benefit as well, however.

Comment: I think your update 3 pen is perfectly fine - it's basically a streamlined pub/sub system, which is a battle-tested pattern. Since you 'own' the viewmodel object, you're in a position to add those event hooks, so why not - I generally take the view that 'if it works, and feels right, then it is right'.

Comment: The `this.get()` thing works because functions that form part of expressions such as `{{ curImageCaption() }}` get *wrapped* - before getting called, the `ractive.get()` function is overwritten so that any calls to it are logged. After the function has finished executing, we see which calls got logged and check those against the existing 'soft dependencies' (i.e. dependencies that aren't explicit in the expression itself), adding watchers to those dependencies as necessary. It's quite similar to the way Knockout handles dependency tracking within functions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an academic exercise, and I'm new to Ractive, but it seems the problem lies in the template not having a context to the current image.

**EDITED**:  Use current Image as a context block instead of looping through collection.

```
  <div class='slideshow'>
    {{#curImage}}
    <div class='main'>
      <a class='prev' on-tap='prev'><span>&laquo;</span></a>
      <div class='main-image' style='background-image: url({{ src }});'></div>
      <a class='next' on-tap='next'><span>&raquo;</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class='caption'>
      <p>{{ caption }}</p>
      <p>Image index: {{ imgIndex }} </p>
    </div>
  </div>

...

    function SlideshowViewModel(imageData) {
      ...
      self.curImage = imageData[self.imgIndex]
      ...
      self.setLegalIndex = function(newIndex) { 
        self.imgIndex = mod(newIndex,imageData.length); 
        self.curImage = imageData[self.imgIndex]
        } 
    }
```

This is using your original pen with just the key modifications. Here is new [pen](http://codepen.io/martypdx/pen/rDvHu).

I would still move the buttons into an outer part of the template so the display in the middle *could* be made into a partial:

```
<div class='main'>
  <a class='prev' on-tap='prev'><span>&laquo;</span></a>
  {{#current}}
    {{>partial}}
  {{/}}
  {{/current}}
  <a class='next' on-tap='next'><span>&raquo;</span></a>
</div>
```

and encapsulate in Ractive.extend, but if ViewModel works for you...

Comment: hey marty, i appreciate your replying, but i don't like this solution at all.  it essentially defeats what i consider to be one of the major benefits of using a custom view model: that you can isolate all your display logic in a POJO, letting your view templates be truly passive (basically, self updating mail merge templates).  in your example, display logic sneaks in with `on-tap='move:-1'` and also sneaks into the ractive event handler with `ractive.data.goto(ractive.data.current + i);`.  the isolation is completely lost.

Comment: i just noticed noticed that the template is also looping through every picture in the model with the view, and comparing it `current`,  just to display the correct picture.  baby jesus weeps :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited it staying as close as possible to your original. Key point is to use the curImage as a context

Comment: I was trying to get rid of the duplication in the prev and next event handlers. I agree 'move:-1' is too much, but for me I wouldn't create a separate ViewModel object, I'd just use Ractive.extend. I think Ractive could look for methods on the Ractive instance and call them if they exist rather than (or in addition to) events

Comment: Using Ractive.extend is fine, but it couples your domain model to the ractive framework, when in fact your domain model has nothing to do with ractive.  By using a POJO ViewModel, you can easily switch to another framework.  It also makes unit testing easier, as you're just testing a POJO with no dependencies.  So there are good reasons for doing something that seems overcomplicated on the surface.  As for removing duplication in prev/next, just create a private view model method and let prev/next delegate to that, passing in 1/-1.  It seemed not worth doing to me though.

Comment: Good point on coupling to Ractive framework. After playing around with it some more, it also appears that the Ractive.extend object doesn't work with magic mode. Does having a context block with the current image solve your problem? Or is this a hypothetical to prove out a case where you need to call funcitons on your ViewModel?

Comment: The issue is that you're now coding your view model to suit ractive.  As an example, if you want to use the revealing module pattern and not read properties directly, you can't do it.  In addition, if your view model already exists, you'll now have to change it.  If you're writing from scratch, and don't mind letting ractive influence your programming style a bit, it's totally fine.  You'd still reap the benefits of decoupling from the framework and cleaner testability.  But the solution is not quite as flexible as using adaptors, offical or the unoffical kind I proposed.